# How to make the vertical line of the menu equal with the vertical line of the article?

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to make the vertical line of the menu equal with the vertical line of the article.

[image]

This is de css code of the menu:

```
ul {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
list-style: none;
justify-content: center;
background-color: #0cee44;
padding: 15px;


}

li {
    flex-basis: calc(100%/3);
    text-align: center;
    border-inline-end: 2px solid #FFF;
    padding-inline-start: 5px;
    padding-inline-end: 5px;
}

li:last-child {
    border-inline-end: none;
}


li:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

This is de css code of the article

```
article {
    column-count: 3;
    column-rule: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adjusting the width of the UL or li (depending on the number of li s) in a way that it makes the border to be inline with the article border!

```css
ul {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
list-style: none;
justify-content: center;
background-color: #0cee44;
padding: 15px;
width:100%
}
li:first-child{
width:28%
}
li:nth-child(2){
width:32%
}
```